# Semantic UI does not check select for changes

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

my semantic UI does not recognize then changes made to select. When selecting values in select, semanticUI is also displayed correctly. But not when deselecting, here the view in the sermantic-UI is not updated.

The reverse way works (semantic ui -> select).

```
$(function() {
  $('select').dropdown()
  $('select').addClass('mobile');
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/L2ap8udj/7/

**Edit**: I need something like..

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    $('select').dropdown('set exactly',$('select').val())
}, 1000);
```

But thats too hacky. If I listen for changes in the select, I went in a infinity loop..

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    // loop of death, cause semantic ui's "set exactly" will trigger the change-event too
    $('select').dropdown('set exactly', $(this).val())
    console.log('change');
})
```

Is there no solution?

Comment: It seems fine to me. Can you explain your problem a bit more?

Comment: In the example on the left select the values 1, 2 and 3. Then the values should also be visible on the right. If now the selection on the right is changed, left semantic-ui does not react to the changes. Do you know what I mean? Thanks a lot!